# Possible problem calling users/?filter method searching username with tilde

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm testing curious usernames and I am searching their `user_id` by:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/?filter=username_filter
```

I'm trying to get information about this particular user:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu
```

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/?filter=unutbu returns nothing.

I know this is a corner case; the only thing I found is the Meta Stack Overflow post *[A last tribute to the Tilde](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/44145/a-last-tribute-to-the-tilde)* although I'm not sure if it is related to the same problem.

Comment: I see no tilde here.

Comment: you can  see it here (bottom-left): http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=11

Comment: This is [status-bydesign] for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Jeff's answer to the [deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/25542/display-names-bugs-no-allowed-cant-reset-unset-kills-profile-copy)* linked to from the question you link to:

> Your name is inferred from your openid until you specify a display name. You have no display name specified.
>
> Thus your inferred username is ...
>
> ~quack
>
> ... because it's based on your openid URL. It's not an actual, valid display name.

If you check unutbu's page there's no name specified.

* visible only to 10K+ meta users.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/46757/user-search-doesnt-work-when-name-field-is-empty/46760#46760) to a question that hasn't been deleted.

> These users don't actually have names; we're synthesizing a fake name based on their OpenID string.